# Error when inserting data to MySql

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I have 1 tables and I need to insert two client details at once. However, there is error for me to insert the second client's data to MySql. Also, when both of the results are not able to key in when I insert in the second time.
MySql table:
[image]

This is Html table:

```
   <form name="creditAssessPage2" id="basicform" method="post" action="post.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <tr>
             <td>Occupation</td>
             <td><input type="text"   id="occupationMain" name="occupationMain" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" ></td>
             <td><input type="text"   id="occupationJoint1" name="occupationJoint1" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Employment</td>
            <td contenteditable="true">
            <input list="employTypeList" name="employTypeMain" id="employTypeMain" class="form-control">
                 <datalist id="employTypeList">
                      <option value="">
                      <option value="Self-employed">
                      <option value="Employed">
                      <option value="Unemployed">
                      <option value="Retired">
                 </datalist>
            </td>
            <td contenteditable="true">
                <input list="employTypeList" name="employTypeJoint1" id="employTypeJoint1" class="form-control">
                <datalist id="employTypeList">
                     <option value="">
                     <option value="Self-employed">
                     <option value="Employed">
                     <option value="Unemployed">
                     <option value="Retired">
                </datalist>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Company</td>
            <td><input type="text"   id="companyMain" name="companyMain" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" ></td>
            <td><input type="text"   id="companyJoint1" name="companyJoint1" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" ></td>
        </tr>
        <div class="form-group">
<button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-default">Create</button><br/>
</div>
    </form>
```

This is is my post.php code:

```
<?php 

require_once 'db/dbfunction.php';
require_once 'db/dbCreditAssessment.php';

session_start();
$con = open_connection();



$occupationMain = $_POST['occupationMain'];
$employTypeMain = $_POST['employTypeMain'];
$companyMain = $_POST['companyMain'];

$occupationJoint1 = $_POST['occupationJoint1'];
$employTypeJoint1 = $_POST['employTypeJoint1'];
$companyJoint1 = $_POST['companyJoint1'];

addemployementdetails($con,$occupationMain,$employTypeMain,$companyMain);
addemployementdetails2($con,$occupationJoint1,$employTypeJoint1,$companyJoint1);

close_connection($con);
?>
```

This is the code for dbCreditAssessment.php:

```
<?php

function addemployementdetails($con,$occupationMain,$employTypeMain,$companyMain){

    $query = "insert into employementdetails(Occupation,EmploymentStatus,NameOfBusiness) 
            values('$occupationMain','$employTypeMain','$companyMain')";            
                 //echo "{$sqlString}";



                 $insertResult = mysqli_query($con, $query);


                 if($insertResult){
                     echo " Applicant Detail Added !<br />";
                     echo "<a href='index.php'>Back to Home</a>";
                 }
                 else {
                     echo " Error !";
                     echo "{$query}";
                     //header('Location: post.php');
                 }


}

function addemployementdetails2($con,$occupationJoint1,$employTypeJoint1,$companyJoint1){
    $query2 = "insert into employementdetails(Occupation,EmploymentStatus,NameOfBusiness)
            values('$occupationJoint1','$employTypeJoint1','$companyJoint1')"; 


                 $insertResult2 = mysqli_query($con, $query2);



                 if($insertResult2){
                     echo " Applicant Detail Added !<br />";
                     echo "<a href='index.php'>Back to Home</a>";
                 }
                 else {
                     echo " Error !";
                     echo "{$query2}";
                     //header('Location: post.php');
                 }
}
```

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: Error !insert into employementdetails(Occupation,EmploymentStatus,NameOfBusiness) values('qweee','Not working','qweeee') Error !insert into employementdetails(Occupation,EmploymentStatus,NameOfBusiness) values('eeeewq','Not working','eeeeewq') Applicant Detail Added !

Comment: Provide the mysql error message

Comment: your code seems sql injection vulnerability possible . try to use prepared statement .to avoid sql injection

Comment: #1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 'PRIMARY'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, your table has attribute **EmploymentDetailsID** as the Primary key which must have unique in each entry. But you are not inserting unique value in each entry. Now the solution for this problem is given below...

Alter table and make **EmploymentDetailsID** auto increment column. And for this purpose you can use code given below...

> ALTER TABLE employementdetails MODIFY COLUMN EmploymentDetailsID varchar auto_increment

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the design of MySql table, employementdetails table need to have AI ID. In this case, employementdetailsID have to be auto generated.